# Retrieving a RequestToken with .NET Core in C# using FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, c#, .net

I'm trying to write a small SFMC API so that I can integrate it with our SQL server. After a few hours of failing to get this working in a SQL procedure (which would be ideal) I decided to give .NET a try.

I'm trying to get my RequestToken so I can read and write to DataExtensions. RequestToken Docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm

I installed FuelSDK through NuGet, but I am not able to get this working in C#. Although I'm new to .NET, I have experience with C#. I'm sure I'm almost there. My method is below:

```
    [HttpGet("/sfmc/requestToken/")]
    public async Task<string> RequestToken()
    {
        string endpoint = "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken"; 
        string clientId = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";
        string clientSecret = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "clientId", clientId },
                { "clientSecret", clientSecret }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(endpoint), content);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give some more details about what exactly is not working?  Is there a specific exception that you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I was able to solve this issue in SFMC. This code is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
    string endpoint = "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com";

    [HttpGet("/sfmc/requestToken/")]
    public async Task<string> RequestToken()
    {

        string clientId = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";
        string clientSecret = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "clientId", clientId },
                { "clientSecret", clientSecret }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(endpoint + "/v1/requestToken"), content);
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseString);

            return (string) responseObject.accessToken;
        }
    }
```